# Click on edit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I am a newbie so my question is pretty simple and straight forward.

I have a simple html text. When I click on that html text, the text should change to input field with the value retained and when the user clicks outside the text box, the input text field now should change to html text.

```
<div class="myText"> Hellow World </div>
```

Can somebody do this in jquery/Meteor. I am actually building a meteor project

Comment: In short, adding an onClick event which changes the text into an input. with .html(). Also add an onBlur event which changest the class back to the  value of the current inputbox with .val()

Comment: It is pretty tricky as an algorithm... you should try to keep things plain and simple, less headaches, imho.

Comment: It is quite simple: look into the [contenteditable attribute](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable)!

Answer (score 12):

You can do that with the [`contenteditable` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp)

```
<div class="myText" contenteditable="true"> Hellow World </div>
<!-- Your div is now editable -->
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Updated DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe4t1mb0/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editable').on('click', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.find('input').length > 0) {
            return;
        }
        var currentText = that.text();

        var $input = $('<input>').val(currentText)
        .css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            top: '0px',
            left: '0px',
            width: that.width(),
            height: that.height(),
            opacity: 0.9,
            padding: '10px'
        });

        $(this).append($input);

        // Handle outside click
        $(document).click(function(event) {
            if(!$(event.target).closest('.editable').length) {
                if ($input.val()) {
                    that.text($input.val());
                }
                that.find('input').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In my solution you need to add `class="editable"` to all editable divs.

You also need to set `position: relative` to these divs. May be you can update my code and edit the css:

```
.editable {
  position: relative;
}
```

To correctly align the `input` inside the div, you need to remove the border or set the `.css({})` of the input to `left: -1px` and `top: -1px`. The border actually pushes the input 1px left and 1px form the top.

Comment: Very good solution, but it seems that the html tags  will not be preserved, is there any solution?

Comment: @vanabel What you mean, in which way the html tags will not be preserved?

Comment: I mean, if there has some html tags in the `.editable` element, for example
`<div class='editable">
<b>Strong</b><br />This supposed in the second line.
</div>`
Then after click outside, then the html tags will lost?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.myText').on('click', function() {
    var div = $(this);
    var tb = div.find('input:text');//get textbox, if exist
    if (tb.length) {//text box already exist
      div.text(tb.val());//remove text box & put its current value as text to the div
    } else {
      tb = $('<input>').prop({
        'type': 'text',
        'value': div.text()//set text box value from div current text
      });
      div.empty().append(tb);//add new text box
      tb.focus();//put text box on focus
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myText">Hello world</div>
<div class="myText">This is second</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.myText').html("Hello World");
});

$(".myText").click(function(event) {
  $('.myText').html("<input type='text' id='test' value='Hello World'/>");
  $('#test').focus();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/nm40tjmL/).

Answer (score 1):

To do it very easily and understandable you can also make two elements instead of changing.
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/45utpzhx/

It does an onClick event and onBlur.

html

```
<div>
    <span class="myText">Hello World</span>
    <input class="myInput"  />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".myText").click(function() { 
  $(this).hide();
  var t = $('.myText').html();
  $('.myInput').val(t);
  $('.myInput').show();
 });

 $(".myInput").blur(function() {  

  $(this).hide();
  var t = $('.myInput').val();
  $('.myText').html(t);
  $('.myText').show();

 });
});
```

Comment: blur don't work first time when you click on element in that case, you need to click twice on text, only then blur event will triger in this case

Comment: @MarekKus add a focus event to it

Answer (score 0):

Replace the clicked element with an input with value equal to the clicked element's text

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myText', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var text = that.text();
  that.wrap('<div id="wrp" />');
  $('#wrp').html('<input type="text" value="' + text + '" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myText"> Hellow World </div>
```

Comment: OP also asked to change input back to div if user leaves the field. ;)

Comment: The OP also asked to revert the `<input>` back to the HTML if the user clicks outside the box. For this I'd recommend attaching an event to the `body`, and in the handler function checking for the CSS class `myText` on the clicked element; if not present then revert to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution :

```
$('.myText').click(function(){
  var m = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('');
  $('<input/>',{
    value : m
  }).appendTo(this).focus();
});

$(document).on('blur','input',function(){
  var m = $(this).val();    
  $(this).parent().find('input').remove().end().html(m);

});
```

working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/ame9mftr/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#text').on('click', function() {
$("#text").hide();
        if ($("#text").text()=="Add New text"){
$('#in_text').val("");
}else{
$('#in_text').val($("#text").text());

}
$("#in_text").show();
            });
        // Handle outside click
$(document).click(function(event) {
            if(!$(event.target).closest('.editable').length) {
         if($("#text").css('display') == 'none'){
        $("#in_text").hide();
        if ($("#in_text").val()==""  ){
        $('#text').text("Add New text");
        $('#text').addClass("asd");
        }else{
        $('#text').removeClass("asd");
        $('#text').text($("#in_text").val());
        }
        $("#text").show();
}
   }
        });
```

```css
#in_text{
  display:none;
}
.editable{ 
width:50%;

}
.asd{
  border-bottom : 1px dashed #333;
}
#text{
display: inline;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable">
<div id="text" >Text in div</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Text" id="in_text"/></div>
```