# simulating clicking on element by js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have an menu of tabs that contains title by P tag ,which  are edited after being clicked by the mouse.
I tried to simulate an click event on the tab from js ,and it works partially .
it is actually focusing on the element , but there is not response for typing ,what there is to do about it ?

there is a fiddle for this code || https://jsfiddle.net/gcqsyp46/
JS

```
function getIn_tab(element){
    element.style.backgroundColor="rgb(163, 217, 238)";
    $("body").css("pointer-events","none");
    let string ="";
    $(element).on("keydown", function (event) {

            var keyPressed = event.key;
            if (keyPressed === "Enter") {
                console.log("work")
                if(string=="" || string=="title"){
                    $(element.firstElementChild).text("title");
                    $("#blincking_cursor").remove();
                    $(element).unbind("keydown");
                    $("body").css("pointer-events","auto");
                    $(element).removeAttr("pointer-events style");
                }
                else{
                $(element.firstElementChild).text("");  
                $(element.firstElementChild).text(string);
                $("body").css("pointer-events","auto"); 
                //$(element).css("pointer-events","none");
                $("#blincking_cursor").remove();
                $(element).unbind("keydown");
                }
        }
         else{
            if(keyPressed==="Backspace"){
                    $(element.firstElementChild).text("");
                    string=string.slice(0,string.length-1);
                    $(element.firstElementChild).text(string);  
            }
            if(string.length<=20 && keyPressed!=="Backspace"){
                    $(element.firstElementChild).text("");  
                    string+=keyPressed;
                    $(element.firstElementChild).text(string);
            }   
         }
    });
 }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyVac</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="main_container">
    
        <div id=tabs_outerWrapper>
            <div class=arrow id="arrowLeft">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left" onclick="clickLeft()"></i>
             </div>
             <div id=tabs_wrapper>  
                <div class="tab" tabindex="1" onclick="getIn_tab(this)">
                        <!--<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">-->
                        <p>title</p>
                </div>
                <div id=attBtn_wrapper>
                    <i class=" fa fa-plus-circle "aria-hidden="true" onclick="add_tab()"></i> 
                </div >
            </div>
            <div class=arrow id="arrowRight">
                <i class=" fas fa-arrow-circle-right" onclick="clickRight()"></i>
             </div>
        </div>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        word
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        part-speech
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        transcription
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        synonym
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        recort
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        translation
                    </th>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: seashell;
  z-index: 1;
}
@keyframes animate{
   0%{
     opacity: 0;
   }
   50%{
     opacity: 1;
   }
   100%{
     opacity: 0;
   }
 }
#main_container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 8%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: rgb(163, 217, 238);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#tabs_outerWrapper{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 31px;
  width:100%;
}
#tabs_wrapper {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex:90%;
}
.class{
  flex: 5%;
}
#tabs_wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


.arrow{

  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.5s ,opacity 1s;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  padding: 4px;
  height: fit-content;
}
#arrowLeft{
  border-right:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#arrowRight{
  border-left:1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  bottom: 20px;
}
th {
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  flex: auto;
}
tr {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 3vw;
}
.tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 30px;
  min-width:30%;
  background-color: slategray;
  /*border: 1px black solid;*/
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;

}

.tab input {
  color: red;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius:12px;
  border:none;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
}
.tab input:focus{
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgb(163, 217, 238);
}
.tab input::placeholder {
  color: black;
}
.tab p{
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3vw;
}
#blincking_cursor{
   animation: animate .8s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is your question.

Comment: Consider using `.click()` or `.trigger("click")` on the element. Your example is too hard to understand.

Comment: You have an `<input>` element in your HTML, but it is commented out, and AFAICT your code does not actually try to use it?  Do you want to use that input, or are you trying to change text without it?  You're also using a mix of jQuery and plain Javascript which is quite hard to read, eg `$(element.firstElementChild)`. I can't understand exactly what you are trying to do in the code, and I don't see where you are trying to simulate a click?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, there are many examples here of making text editable on click, can you use those?  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/30070374/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/16202723/6089612, ...